# Windows XP/Firewall -- Can't open UDP port 9100 for JetDirect sharing

Tags: windows-xp, windows-firewall, hp-laserjet

I'm setting up my Dad's laptop (Vista) to print to an HP Deskjet printer attached to a Windows XP Desktop box. The XP box is running Windows firewall.

Laptop sits on 192.168.1.66, Desktop 192.168.1.65.

I set up logging in the firewall, and determined that it is dropping inbound packets on TCP port 9100, used by JetDirect, the printing protocol.

I set up an exception on TCP port 9100, allowing access to the local subnet. There's also an entry under the 'allow applications' tab which was marked for the exact printer model. I selected this as well, then tried to print again... I see more dropped packets from 192.168.1.66 to 192.168.1.65 for TCP port 9100.

What do I try next?

Answer (score 1):

Have you added file and printer sharing as an exception to the firewall?  That is required.   Also, have you disabled all firewalls and tested to be sure there are no other issues? You indicate the printer is connected to the computer?  How is the JetDirect used?  Normally it would be USB or LPT cable if connected directly.  If JetDirect, it would be connected to Etherenet and you would add it using HP tools. Or manually in Windows.

More detail please around printer model and exact config.

Comment: File and printer sharing were already set as exceptions to the firewall. I'll give other details when I'm back with the printer.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the program is listening on all interfaces. It may only be listening for local connections. TCPView from Sysinternals can show you this, I think.

That said, printer sharing in Windows is normally handled through SMB, not via JetDirect. Port 9100 printing is normally done direct to the device.